# Delete link LinkColumn dosen't work django-tables2

Tags: django, django-templates, django-tables2

I am trying to make a link to the user's remove. I use this djnago-tables2.
In a place where there should be a link to remove have horizontal line.

```
class UsersListTable(BaseTable):
    user = tables.Column(
        order_by=('user__last_name', 'user__first_name'),
        accessor='user.get_full_name',
        verbose_name=_('Employee')
    )

    delete_link = tables.LinkColumn('deleteUser', args=[A('pk')])

    class Meta(BaseTable.Meta):
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('country', 'name', 'delete_link')
        empty_text = _('No users')
```

My view:

```
class DeleteUser(DeleteView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = "templates/list_of_users.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('myapp:base')

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = super(DeleteUser, self).get_object()
        return obj

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('base')
```

My urls:

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DeleteUser.as_view(), name='deleteUser'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TemplateColumn:

```
#tables.py:
TEMPLATE = '''
<a href="{% url 'deleteUser' record.pk %}">delete</a>
'''

class UsersListTable...
   ....
   delete_link = tables.TemplateColumn(TEMPLATE)
```

Another option is render_FOO metod
(https://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latestindex.html?highlight=render_foo)